# Could not connect to MySQL: Unknown database 'logindb'

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, windows-firewall

[image]I am trying to connect to mysql database logindb using a separate **mysqli_connect.php** file. Here is my code:

```
<?php
// This creates a connection to the logindb database and to MySQL,
// It also sets the encoding.
// Set the access details as constants:
DEFINE('DB_USER', 'loger');
DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD', 'loger');
DEFINE('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE('DB_NAME', 'logindb');

// Make the connection:
$dbcon = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or   die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' .
mysqli_connect_error());

// Set the encoding...
mysqli_set_charset($dbcon, 'utf8');

?>
```

I ma using XAAMP on Windows, but I get this error:

> Could not connect to MySQL: Unknown database 'logindb'

Windows Firewall had blocked Apache HTTP and mysql in Inbound Rules, I allowed the connection but still same error.
I am hell confused what is wrong?

**edit**

I think the problem is with Firewall as maybe sql is blocked!
Anyway I uninstalled the XAMPP and reinstalled it and made logindb again and added the user with all the privileges and now it works. Thank You!

Comment: the message says "Unknown database", it looks like the DB you are trying to connect to is named differently...

Comment: create db with named logindb

Comment: db with logindb is already connected and user with all privileges are created i am still getting the error

Comment: Tried with empty password that got this error **Could not connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'sykox'@'localhost' (using password: NO)**

Comment: @Anant will try it out

Comment: It doesn't shows anything...maybe it works..thanks let me check further...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your error:-

**It seems database with name `logindb` does not exist. So check that once.**

**Also you used `@` while creating connection, may be because of this you are not getting the exact errors which are happening in your code. Because `@` is used for skipping errors.**

So your code looks fine apart from above stated thing.May be it sound crazy too but check once below code:-

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
// Make the connection: 
$dbcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','loger','loger','logindb') or die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' .mysqli_connect_error()); 
// Set the encoding... 
 mysqli_set_charset($dbcon, 'utf8'); 
?>
```

OR try once

```
$dbcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','loger','','logindb') or die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' .mysqli_connect_error());
```

**Also check that password must be correct if you are providing. Because your errors in comment are stating like that you are using wrong password.**

**You can try to create a new user with new password and run the code.**

**After all these works if nothing happen then un-install and re-install the `xampp` again. Thanks**

Comment: I had no idea @ is used for skipping errors... thank you.. anyway i tried above code and got this **Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'loger'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\abc.php on line 5
Could not connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'loger'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

Comment: I think I better uninstall XAMPP and reinstall the damn thing and make completely new start...

Comment: Let me Do that...just a sec

Comment: **Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'logindb' in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\abc.php on line 6
Could not connect to MySQL: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'logindb'**

Comment: Actually thank you...from the error of **Unknown database 'logindb'** it is now just having problem with user so let me make a new user and try....

Comment: Thank You @Anant Problem Solved!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the @ attribute and figure out the error produced correctly.

Comment: Got this warning on removing @ **Warning: mysqli_connect()**